# iterate over dict to find identical values in python

Tags: python, loops, search

let's assume I have `x = (600, 800 , 700)` and I have also the following dict:

[image]

I want to find the equivalent values for x from the dict (which is highlighted in the picture)
knowing that the values in dict might be swapped in an unknown order.

Is that possible without writing complex searching code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we want just to know if there is a match for numbers in values_to_find and in dict_to search, we can use `all(...)`, and no sorting is required:

```
value_to_find = (600, 800, 700)

dict_to_search = {
    'key_01':(40, 300, 300),
    'key_02':(800, 500, 1000),
    'key_03':(500, 1000, 200),
    'key_04':(800, 700, 600)
}

for k, v in dict_to_search.items():
    if all([i in value_to_find for i in v]):
        print(k)
```

the result is: `'key_04'`

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the values you're looking for and sort each entry in the dictionary before the comparison:

```py
value_to_find = (600, 800, 700)

dict_to_search = {
    'key_01':(40, 300, 300),
    'key_02':(800, 500, 1000),
    'key_03':(500, 1000, 200),
    'key_04':(800, 700, 600)
}

value_to_find = sorted(value_to_find)
for key in dict_to_search:
    sorted_value = sorted(dict_to_search[key])
    if sorted_value == value_to_find:
        print(f'matching values found against {key}: {dict_to_search[key]}')
        break
```

Output:

```
matching values found against key_04: (800, 700, 600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of the numbers is irrelevant, you can convert the tuples to sets (which are unordered) and then simply check for equality.

```py
value_to_find = (600, 800, 700)

dict_to_search = {
    'key_01':(40, 300, 300),
    'key_02':(800, 500, 1000),
    'key_03':(500, 1000, 200),
    'key_04':(800, 700, 600)
}

result = []
for key,value in dict_to_search.items():
    if set(value) == set(value_to_find):
        result.append(key)

print(result)
```

This outputs `['key_04']`

You could also use list comprehension to do it in one line

```py
result = [key for key,value in dict_to_search.items() if set(value)==set(value_to_find)]
```